# Nothing in Logcat when I write Android service

Tags: android

There is nothing in Logcat even the app force close when I just write Android Service without Andorid Activity.
Is there any problem?

Comment: click on the device at the left panel, and/or unselect filters.

Answer (score 2):

Normally at least ActivityManager should tell it is killing the application when you close it. Hence yes, there is a problem.

If you are viewing logcat from IDE, check your filters (usually inside panel on the left) and log level. For instance, it may be relative silence if the level set to `error`.

Another possible situation is that you have multiple active devices and/or emulators. IDE logcat viewer sometimes gets confused in such cases, showing only messages from the different device.

To see logcat messages directly (not through IDE), login into device with `adb shell` and type `logcat`.